# What is it about this function that makes it not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6, ssh-tunnel

This is a noob question. When I run app.js I'm getting the error `createTunnelToMongoDB is not a function`. I'm trying to access my database using [tunnel-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tunnel-ssh). Can someone please explain to me why I can't do it this way?

Path: `app.js`

```
    const createTunnelToMongoDB = require("./createTunnelToMongoDB.js");

    (async function app() {
      try {
        // create a tunnel
        const tunnel = await createTunnelToMongoDB();
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("our error", e);
      }
    })();
```

Path: `createTunnelToMongoDB.js`

```
const tunnel = require("tunnel-ssh");
const fs = require("fs");

var config = {
  username: "root",
  privateKey: require("fs").readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../../id_rsa")),
  ...etc
};
var tnl = tunnel(config, function(error, tnl) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  return tnl;
});

module.exports = tnl;
```

Comment: Not enough information. Where is `tunnel` coming from in `createTunnelToMongoDB.js`? How is `createTunnelToMongoDB` being imported in `app.js`?

Comment: Need some more info here bud. Is tunnel defined elsewhere? How is createTunnelToMongoDB being imported - we can't see that here.

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku. Please see the update.

Comment: It means that `tunnel(config, …)` does not return a function. Why did you expect it to?

Comment: I need it to wait until the tunnel connection has occurred before moving onto the next step. I thought this was the correct way to do it. @Bergi

Comment: @bp123 tunnel-ssh doesn't appear well-documented, but it seems that is what the callback is for. You should export a promise (or a function creating one) and resolve that from the callback.

Comment: @Bergi, would you mind showing me what you mean?

Comment: you need to use require, your not using ECMA modules you using common js `module.exports = tnl;` you need to use `require`

Answer (score 0):

`createTunnelToMongoDB.js` exports an object, the result of a call to `tunnel`:

```
var tnl = tunnel(config, function(error, tnl) {
  // ...
});

module.exports = tnl;
```

It doesn't export a function, so when you try to invoke it, Node correctly tells you that it is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

It appears `createTunnelToMongoDB.js` is not imported into `app.js`.

Try editing `app.js` to:

```js
import { tnl as createTunnelToMongoDB } from "./createTunnelToMongoDB.js";

(async function app() {
  try {
    // create a tunnel
    const tunnel = await createTunnelToMongoDB();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("our error", e);
  }
})();
```

Comment: I get the error `import { tnl as createTunnelToMongoDB } from "./createTunnelToMongoDB.js";
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Comment: It looks like the error is because EMCAScript 6 `import` syntax is not available. Try the ES5 syntax: `const createTunnelToMongoDB = require("./createTunnelToMongoDB.js").tnl;`

Comment: you're forgetting the fact that @bp123 is using common js not ECMA modules. `module.exports = tnl`, the import statement won't work here